# Laravel posts and tags: has many through relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm making a Laravel application.

I have a posts table that stores "blog posts". I also have a tags table to store tags (eg: "Cooking" for cooking posts, "Books" for book posts). Each post can have many tags. I setup my database as such

Posts

- id
- text
- title

Tags

- id
- name

PostTags

- id
- tag_id
- post_id

Is this a "HasManyThrough" relationship in Laravel/Eloquent? I tried setting up my model using

```
public function tags()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Tag', 'App\PostTag')
}
```

However, this isn't working - throwing exceptions telling me the column names don't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was actually a "belongsToMany" relationship - what I was missing was the fact you can specify a pivot table using an argument when declaring the relationship like so:

```
public function tags()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'post_tags')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not a has-many-through relationship.

A post can belong to many tags (e.g: post "Foobar" can belong to "foo" and "bar" tags). A tag can belong to many posts (e.g: tag "foo" can belong to posts "Foobar" and "Another post").

So, in a Post class you would have

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

and in the Tag class you would define the inverse

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}
```

Read more in the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).